# Como utilizar um arquivo .JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

Sou extremamente novo na linguagem JSP, queria saber como fazer para utilizar um arquivo jsp que eu criei e exibilo por exemplo no browser, da mesma forma que faço com arquivos html, ou seja, como utilizar um arquivo jsp criado???
**obs**: na imagem anexada está o resultado quando abro o arquivo .jsp com o browser(que não é a saída que eu desejo).

```
<%! int i %>
<html>
  <head>
         <title> Pagina JSP Ola Mundo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <% for(i = 0; i = 3; i++){ %>
        <div>
          <%out.println("numero:"+i);%>
        </div>
    <%
       }
    %>
  </body>

</hmtl>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem que configurar um Web Conteiner, um exemplo o Tomcat. Outra coisa já que você esta começando, procura saber mais sobre JSF. No youtube tem muitas aulas para iniciantes em JSP, JSF, nelas você consegue aprender a configurar um servidor e rodar sua primeira página com tecnologia Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não consegue abrir um arquivo JSP diretamente no navegador pois ele é uma linguagem "acima" do HTML. Isso significa que você precisa de um container web para identificar os componentes JSP do arquivo e permitir a sua visualização como um arquivo HTML. O navegador não tem o suporte nativo para identificar esses componentes e é por isso que você precisa que o seu projeto que contém a JSP inclua as bibliotecas `jsp-api` e `jstl`, que são usadas pelo container web para renderizar a página.

Um exemplo mínimo de aplicação web usando JSP pode ser visto nesse [link](http://www.codejava.net/coding/java-servlet-and-jsp-hello-world-tutorial-with-eclipse-maven-and-apache-tomcat).

Answer (score 0):

Instale o Tomcat :

http://tomcat.apache.org

Com o Tomcat instalado pode-se iniciar o desenvolvimento JSP. Para iniciar o desenvolvimento deve-se criar um diretório easyjava em C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps (no Windows) e /usr/java/apache-tomcat-7.0 (no Linux)”.

Salve o arquivo e abra o navegador de sua preferencia e digite: http://127.0.0.1:8080/easyjava/ola.jsp, conforme a Figura 1.

[image: Figura 1]